# Rails 4 compiled assets only works after server reboot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, asset-pipeline, vps

I deploy my Rails app using Capistrano 3 and rails 4, and ubuntu VPS, but the compiled assets cannot be found after deployment, it always return route error, I had to reboot my server, then it will work.

restart Nginx and Unicorn doesn't help.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
rake assets:precompile
```

before deployment

Comment: This will not work unless you did not change any css code within your most recent deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I do the following when deploying latest changes:

I pull my latest version from Github.
I run

`bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

`sudo service nginx restart`

Now when accessing your website the code will be loaded into the RAM with your assets being served correctly.

You need to disable static assets serving in your config/environments/production.rb
`config.serve_static_assets = false`

Hope I could help you.